# What is the correct HTTP status code for a PUT request on a resource without supplying an id?

Tags: http, zend-framework, rest

So I have a RESTful api module which has several resources. I am trying to figure out what should be the correct HTTP status code in a situation when a user makes PUT request on a resource but without identifying a specific resource with an id.

Let's say:

```
PUT http://example.com/api/resource
```

I only allow PUT requests on specific resource such as:

```
PUT http://example.com/api/resource/1234
```

What HTTP response should I return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case I usually return 405 together with the Allow-Header to show which methods are allowed

> 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the
>   resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an
>   Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested
>   resource.